# How can I launch Intellij idea from the linux terminal?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, terminal

It can be easily run from its bin directory by using "./idea.sh". But how can I open it anyware else with "idea ." or "idea pom.xml".

I tried to add the directory of IntelliJ installation to my PATH environment in order to launch it from anywhere using the command:

`PATH=$PATH:/opt/Jetbrains/idea-IU-231.9225.16/bin`